# Preserving newlines in body of \NewDocumentEnvironment when writing to an external file

Tags: expl3, external-files, xparse

I am working on a system for providing hints for exercises in a different location of the typeset document.
The current approach is based on saving the content of the hint environment to a file.
This sort of works, but is problematic when used on verbatim content that covers multiple lines.
The issue appears to be that newlines in the body of the hint environment are removed before the
content is written to the file.

After running the code given at the end of the question, I would like the following content to be in the file "hintfile.tex"

```
Example
d
with 
multiple lines.
```

The content of the file is the following after running the code

```
Example d with multiple lines.
```

Here comes the code for the example

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Open a file for writing
\iow_new:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {hintfile.tex}

% Create an environment that saves the body 
% to the opened file
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { #2 }
}{}

% Create command to close the file
\NewDocumentCommand{\closehintandsolutionfile}{}{
\iow_close:N \g_hintfile_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello world

\begin{hint}
Example
d
with 
multiple lines.
\end{hint}

\begin{verbatim}
Example
d
with 
multiple lines.
\end{verbatim}

\section{From external file}

\closehintandsolutionfile
\input{hintfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `answers` package already do what you want? And there are also `probsoln` and `xsim` packages for this kind of problem

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for the references to `answers`, `probsoln` and `xsim`. They do something close to what I want to achieve, but do not hit it exactly. I miss the possibility to easy jump from exercise to solution and back again (via a hyperlink). See an example of that in this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574264/1366

Comment: Well, see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/examples and check the crossref example (`xsim`) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581052/ (`answers`). I'm willing to bet it's possible with `probsoln`, too.

Comment: @cgnieder Fantastic, thanks for the examples! Next thing I have to add is the option of providing one or more hints for exercises. The trick used in the example for the `answers` package for checking the presence of a latex command seems very handy for generating hyperlinks to the hints and solution from the exercise.

Comment: I'll add an example for an implementation of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574264/ to the `xsim` examples folder in the next update. It needed some effort but is doable... (I'd rather not add it as answer to the question as it doesn't answer it, strictly speaking)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you, you can store the content in memory or in external files:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, log] }
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\newenvsc{hint}[store-env=hint,print-env=false]
\begin{document}
Hello world

% hiden and write
\begin{hint}[write-env=hint1.txt]
Example
d
with
multiple lines.
\end{hint}

\begin{verbatim}
Example
d
with
multiple lines.
\end{verbatim}

\section{From memory}

\typestored[1]{hint}

\section{From file}

\input{hint1.txt}

\end{document}
```

I recommend reading the documentation.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse} % added

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Open a file for writing
\iow_new:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {hintfile.tex}

% Create an environment that saves the body 
% to the opened file
\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} #2 }
}{}

% Create command to close the file
\NewDocumentCommand{\closehintandsolutionfile}{}{
\iow_close:N \g_hintfile_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello world

\begin{hint}
Example \\  
d \\    
with \\ 
multiple lines.
\end{hint}

\begin{verbatim}
Example
d
with 
multiple lines.
\end{verbatim}

\section{From external file}

\closehintandsolutionfile
\input{hintfile}
\end{document}
```

[image: x]